# Value is null even if it's not in console.log (...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular and I'm trying to access property img of my object, and when I'm doing `console.log(..)` of my whole object. Value is there, but when I'm doing c`onsole.log(..)` of object's property it said it's null.

```
console.log("Product:", this.article);
var url = this.article.img;
console.log("Image" , url);
```

Console:

[image]

[image]

I don't know how is this possible if `this.article.img`; looks like has some value in `console.log`. But when I try to access it, it says it's null. How come?

Comment: Why are there two images ? Can you build a MCVE ? Try `console.dir` too.

Comment: type of Article, which is my database Entity Model, should I post an articles type definition?

Comment: does the Article object have some getter that you need to use? did you write the Article class, or is this from some library? Some models in some libraries require you to use their getter instead of '.'.

Answer (score 8):

The object isn't rendered immediately. Your `img` property has a `null` value at logging time but when you open the object in the console, later, it's filled.

You can check that by logging `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.article))`.

The most probable reason of your problem is some asynchronous code whose achievement you're not correctly waiting for. As the object is taken from a database as you said, I guess you forget to use the object in the callback (which might be promise based).

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.article))` indeed shows img as null, and `console.log(this.article)` does not, how is that possible?

Comment: This not the problem. All he needs to do is access it via this.article.img[0]

Comment: @billy_56 That's because big objects in the console are rendered when you click the small triangle at the left. They may have changed since they were logged.

Comment: @billy_56 This is because variables are passed into `console.log` by reference. Using a construct like `JSON.stringify` creates a new local variable context of the type `string`. But if you only print a variable using `console.log` it will always output the current variable value as it is stored in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of logging:

```
console.log("Product:", this.article);
var url = this.article.img;
console.log("Image" , url);
```

try [debugging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger), so that you can inspect the value in real time:

```
console.log("Product:", this.article);
debugger;
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure this should be downvoted, especially without comment. This isn't really an answer but it's a good advice.

Answer (score 0):

Because the browser console works with references in most modern clients:

> Please be warned that if you log objects in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox what you get logged on the console is a reference to the object, which is not necessarily the 'value' of the object at the moment in time you call console.log(), but it is the value of the object at the moment you click it open.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log